# How to match end of line?

Tags: java, regex

How can I tell to match everything up to a specific character set, *or* EOL?

`[=]+.*?[()|$]`

matches: `==test)`

does not match: `==test`

Why is the end of line regex anchor `$` not taken into account for the 2nd statement?

Comment: If you use `Pattern.MULTILINE`, then `(?:[()]|$)` will match up to a bracket or the end of the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

End of line does not work in a character class, because it is not actually a character.  It is a zero-width assertion (it tests a condition at the current point in the string, but doesn't actually eat up a character).

Test for it with `(?:otherstuffhere|$)`.

*Note: you seem to be confusing a character class with a matching subgroup.  A character class `[...]` matches any one character within the brackets. `[a|bc]` will match either `a`, `|`, `b` or `c`. Matching subgroups are what you want to OR multiple expressions. `(...)` is a matching subgroup with capturing. `(?:...)` is a matching subgroup without capturing.*

Note that the matching behavior of `$` can vary in a multi-line string based on your settings.  It could either match the end of each line, or only the end of the string.

`\z` will *always* match at the end of the string only, no matter what settings you use. `\Z` will match either at the end of the string, or right before a newline at the very end.

Comment: Great, so my exp would evaluate to: `(?:[()]|\z)`